# Referring an equation inside a theorem

Tags: cross-referencing

I have theorems which `LaTeX` numbers and then some equations inside and outside theorems that LateX has numbered.

When I refer to an  equation inside a theorem statement then `LaTeX` is referring to it by the theorem's number and not the equation's number.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\begin{prop}
Blah is 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Blah}
B=L+a-H
\end{equation}
\end{prop}

From equation ~\ref{eq:Blah} we know blah blah blah.
```

Suppose the proposition number is `4.1` and the equation number is `12` then my text catches `4.1` and not `12`. I don't particularly care which number is catches, so long as it is consistent. So that someone reading the text can find what I am referring to.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this comes down to where you are putting your `\label`; in your example the reference works as expected... Presumably this is a stripped-down version of the actual problem?

Comment: By the way, if you put a real space in front of an unbreakable space `~`, what you get is a regular breakable space.

Comment: Please clarify if my comment is correct, and update your question with a MWE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating correct labels for referencing forms part of a two-step process:

1. A counter is increased using `\refstepcounter` (a "referencable" form of counter incrementation). This typically happens when you call a macro (like `\section`) or environment. Here's a snapshot of `\refstepcounter` from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

   ```
   \def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
       \protected@edef\@currentlabel
          {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
   }
   ```

   See that `\refstepcounter` is a "modified `\stepcounter`", since it also updates `\@currentlabel`.
2. When inserting a `\label`, the default behaviour of LaTeX is to write the macro `\@currentlabel` and `\thepage` to the `.aux` file as arguments to `\newlabel`. Here's a snapshot of `\label` from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

   ```
   \def\label#1{\@bsphack
     \protected@write\@auxout{}%
            {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
     \@esphack}
   ```

   Generally speaking, `\newlabel` here is just a mechanism built in to check whether a label already exists/not and warn you thereof (in the form of "There were multiply-defined labels" or "Label `...' multiply defined").

So, whenever a `\refstepcounter` is performed, `\@currentlabel` is updated and therefore would change any reference created with a `\label`. The most commonly identified problem of this incorrect labelling is when users perform (say)

```
\begin{figure}
  % Image stuff here
  \label{mylabel}
  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
```

and receive an incorrect reference to their figure. This is because `\caption` executes `\refstepcounter` and not the `figure` environment itself, resulting in an incorrect `\@currentlabel` to be written to the `.aux` file (whatever that may be). A practical example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
See Figure~\ref{fig:ref} in section~\ref{sec:ref}.
\section{A section} Here is some text. \label{sec:ref}
\begin{figure}[bh!]
  \centering\rule{.8\textwidth}{.2\textheight}
  \label{fig:ref}\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note how the figure reference `\ref{fig:ref}` returns `2` instead of `1`. That's because an issue of `\label{fig:ref}` write `\@currentlabel` which is still set to `2` by the preceding `\section`. Switching around `\label` and `\caption` would yield the desired result (however simplistic).

Bottom line is that there's an appropriate placement of `\label` with respect to counters, otherwise references *might* be incorrect. The emphasis here denotes the fact that some environments gather content a post-process them, possibly correcting for inappropriate placements of things like `\label`.